# socket.io and node.js 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, socket.io-1.0

i've got this error requests.

[image]

The red coloured Request getting Error - 400 Bad request and it taking more then 30sec .After the error the socket work fine but it taking more time for response

In app.js the code is follows

```
 var app = express(),
      server = require('http').createServer(app); 
      //io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
      var sockets = require('socket.io')({
      'transports': ['websocket', 'flashsocket','htmlfile','xhr-polling','jsonp-polling']
      });
      var io = sockets.listen(server,{ resource: '/socket.io/','sync disconnect on unload':true });
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('server_emit');
  socket.on('search', function(cattype,pagNo,lang,film,iteamcat,starname){
    var query={'ProductType':cattype,'Language':lang,'ProductCategory':iteamcat,'UsedBy':starname,'UsedIn':film},
    field={},
    options={};

    db.collection("Product").find(query,field,options).toArray(function(error, Product2){     
      socket.emit('result',Product2);
    });




  });
```

In client side code

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('server_emit', function(){
                console.log("Server emitted to Browser")
        });

</script>
```

Please help

Comment: where is the connect URL?

Comment: sorry, that i missed in this question

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the full URL as

```
<script src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'>
```

and in `socket` var

```
= io.connect('http://localhost:3000/')
```

Comment: Why would this fix it?